# Код выдаёт ошибку через время

Tags: python, бот, discord.py, discord, disnake

Через время код выдаёт ошибку

> `disnake.errors.DiscordServerError: 503 Service Unavailable (error code: 0): 503: Service Unavailable`

и перестаёт работать.

Код:

```
@Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self) -> None:
        self.admin_discipline_table.start()


@tasks.loop(seconds=10)
    async def admin_discipline_table(self):
        channel = self.bot.get_channel(Config.BOT_ADMIN_DISCIPLINE_TABLE_CHANNEL)
        last_message = await channel.history(limit=1).flatten()

        database_bot.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `admins`")
        data = database.cursor.fetchall()

        table = ''.join(
            f"* ‼️ `{user['reprimands']} / {Config.ADMIN_MAX_REPRIMANDS}`{self.step('{} / {}'.format(user['reprimands'], Config.ADMIN_MAX_REPRIMANDS))}|    `{user['warnings']} / {Config.ADMIN_MAX_WARNINGS}` ❗{self.step('{} / {}'.format(user['warnings'], Config.ADMIN_MAX_REPRIMANDS))}-    <@{user['discord_id']}>\n"
            for user in data
        )

        embed = Embed(
            title=f"Тест",
            description=f"**{table}**",
            color=Colour.dark_magenta() if database.get_status() else Colour.dark_red(),
        )
        if last_message and last_message[0].author == self.bot.user:
            await last_message[0].edit(embed=embed)
        else:
            await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

И так со всеми тасками.
**Что делать?**